# What is the correct function definition syntax in CoffeeScript?

Tags: syntax, coffeescript

On [the official CoffeeScript website](http://coffeescript.org/#literals) the syntax for defining a function is

```
square = (x) -> x * x
```

However, on some [other websites](http://justinreid.com/coffeescript-global-classes/) I found out that the syntax could also be

```
square: (x) -> x * x
```

Is one of the options preferred?

Comment: You could paste both versions to the [CoffeeScript online compiler](http://goo.gl/WNIjtC).

Answer (score 3):

There is a huge difference between those two options. Firstly, they have nothing to do with function syntax, which is always `(x) -> x * x`. They only differs in what you are doing with the function.

The first option defines a local variable `square` and assign that function to it.  hence afterwards you can simply call `square(2)` to get 4.

Second option is creating a javascript object. If this is the last line of some function, this is its return value. Object has to be assigned to some variable, otherwise it is lost:

```
functions = 
  square: (x) -> x * x

functions.square(2)
```